# Unexpected Behavior Using MVC Razor's Html.Encode HTML Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, encode

I am attempting to display literal HTML to the browser via my Razor View.

I have something like this in the code:

```
@Html.Encode("<!-- foo -->")
```

I was expecting the Html.Encode helper to return

```
&lt;-- foo --&gt;
```

but instead, it returns

```
&amp;lt;!-- foo --&amp;gt;
```

It appears as though the Encode helper encodes the string twice.

So, in order to get the output I want, I have to wrap the Encode helper with the Raw helper like this

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode("<!-- foo -->"))
```

I'm new to MVC/Razor, so this behavior has me a bit confused as well as unsure as to whether or not my expectations of how Html.Encode *should* behave, is correct.

Moving forward w/ Razor, should I suck it up and get in the habit of wrapping Html.Encode with Html.Raw when I want to encode a string to HTML? Is there a "better" way to encode HTML string in Razor?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/dont-call-htmlencode-in-razor.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` operator already HTML encodes in Razor (unless the argument is an [`IHtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx) instance). So you may try:

```
@("<!-- foo -->")
```

which renders:

```
&lt;!-- foo --&gt;
```

Answer (score 4):

The @ syntax performs HTML encoding. By using @Html.Encode you're manually encoding, and then the @ encodes what you've already encoded.

So, to get what you want simply do

```
@("<!-- foo -->")
```